# Python - How to get variable from netcdf file on a specific location and at different level

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, netcdf

I am learning on how to plot various variables from WRF output netcdf file. My requirement is to extract variables for a certain lat/lon (8.4875° N, 76.9525° E) in order to plot SkewT profiles using the matplotlib package.

I found a similar question on this SO page [netcdf4 extract for subset of lat lon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135885/netcdf4-extract-for-subset-of-lat-lon). However, its location is a set of boundaries.

Comment: See answer two at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789379/netcdf-and-python-finding-the-closest-lon-lat-index-given-actual-lon-lat-values/33793437#33793437

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I executed your code it returned `1632` and `43` for lat `8.4` and lon `76.95`. This is no way close to the actual Lat & Lon I would expect.

Comment: 76.95 E is -76.95 in decimal degrees.  I added code to show how to test the results at the answer above.

Comment: Well I have got the index error `IndexError: index 1632 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 73`. Does it mean that the lat and lon is not available in the file?

Comment: I am not at all familiar with the WRF NetCDF file format.  A quick looks suggests that the lat,lon columns might be named south_north and west_east.  Do you have the url where you got the WRF file.

Comment: The file I use is a quite big one and cant be uploaded. You can use the sample file from here http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/wrfout_v2_Lambert.nc

Answer (score 1):

Check out [xray](http://xray.readthedocs.org). You'll have to do some work to make the SkewT chart but accessing and summarizing the netCDF Dataset and variables will be pretty easy.  Just a few examples below.

```
import xray

ds = xray.open_dataset('your_wrf_file.nc')

ds_point = ds.sel(lon=76.9525, lat=8.4875)

ds_point['Temperature'].plot()  # plot profile at point assuming Temperature had dimensions of (level, lat, lon)

df = ds_point.to_dataframe()  # export dataset to Pandas.DataFrame

temp_array = ds_point['Temperature'].values  # access the underlying numpy array of the "Temperature" variable
```

Comment: Your code gives me a key error. I have changed the key to `XLAT` and `XLONG` which is equivalent of `lon` and `lat`. But still same issue.

Comment: You didn't provide a sample file so this was just to give you a rough idea of how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is extract the nearest gridpoint to the column using CDO from the command line before using ncl,python,R etc for plotting:

```
cdo remapnn,lon=76.9525/lat=8.4875 wrf_file.nc pnt_file.nc
```