# indices of 2D lat lon data

Tags: python, coordinates, indices, ncl

I am trying to find the equivalent (if there exists one) of an NCL function that returns the indices of two-dimensional latitude/longitude arrays closest to a user-specified latitude/longitude coordinate pair.

This is the link to the NCL function that I am hoping there is an equivalent to in python.  I'm suspecting at this point that there is not, so any tips on how to get indices from lat/lon coordinates is appreciated

https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Contributed/getind_latlon2d.shtml

Right now , I have my coordinate values saved into an .nc file and are read by:

```
coords='coords.nc'
fh = Dataset(coords, mode='r')
lons = fh.variables['g5_lon_1'][:,:]
lats = fh.variables['g5_lat_0'][:,:]
rot = fh.variables['g5_rot_2'][:,:]
fh.close()
```

Comment: I am wondering something very similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetCDF and Python: Finding the closest lon/lat index given actual lon/lat values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789379/netcdf-and-python-finding-the-closest-lon-lat-index-given-actual-lon-lat-values)

Answer (score 0):

I found scipy  spatial.KDTree can perform similar task. Here is my code of finding the model grid that is closest to the observation location

```
from scipy import spatial
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# read in the one dimensional lat lon info from a dataset
fname = '0k_T_ann_clim.nc'  
fid   = Dataset(fname, 'r')

lat  = fid.variables['lat'][:] 
lon  = fid.variables['lon'][:]
# make them a meshgrid for later use KDTree
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
# zip them together
model_grid = list( zip(np.ravel(lon2d), np.ravel(lat2d)) ) 

#target point location : 30.5N, 56.1E
target_pts = [30.5 56.1]   
distance, index = spatial.KDTree(model_grid).query(target_pts)
# the nearest model location (in lat and lon)
model_loc_coord = [coord for i, coord in enumerate(model_grid) if i==index]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how lon/lat arrays are stored when read in python, so to use the following solution you may need to convert lon/lat to numpy arrays.  You can just put the abs(array-target).argmin() in a function.

```
import numpy as np

# make a dummy longitude array, 0.5 degree resolution.
lon=np.linspace(0.5,360,720)

# find index of nearest longitude to 25.4 
ind=abs(lon-25.4).argmin()

# check it works!  this gives 25.5 
lon[ind]
```